# weird problem with windows 7 dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I first installed Windows 7 and then Ubuntu 17.10 along side the windows. Ubuntu can boot without issue. But if I select Windows7 from the GRUB bootloader, something strange happens.

40% chance the screen turns magenta (same color as GRUB background) and freezes

40% chance the screen turns magenta but the Windows 7 startup sound can be heard

20% chance it can actually boot into Windows 7 without issues

Answer (score 0):

If this is a newer laptop with secure boot and UEFI in the BIOS settings:
[yes manual changes in the BIOS settings]
- turn off secure boot,
- choose legacy in the boot list option
    this will boot Linux,
- choose UEFI in the boot list option
    this will boot Windows,

I've got a Dell I7 7737 and this became the only
way I can sucessfully dual-boot after not being able
to coose Linux/Windows in the GRUB boot screen,

Comment: I'm not sure it has anything to do with UEFI because Win 7 itself does not support UEFI either. Plus there is still a small chance i can boot Win 7 successfully